# ubuntu 19.04, headphones not working, right after installation

Tags: alsa, 19.04, headphones

Internal speakers are working, no headphone sound even when tested from settings. Checked alsamixer from terminal, not muted.

Comment: could you provide more information? maybe take a screenshot of the sound options (`alt`+`prtScr`) ? have the headphones been tested alsewhere? was the output jack hole tested functional with another OS? did you change the output after plugging it in?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i figured it out seems my headphone cord was damaged. sorry for wasting your time. really glad to be here.